# 3rd Monitor in a dual monitor setup with switch leaves one blank

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, external-display, ubuntu-14.04

I have basically a dual monitor setup which works well. I have however, until recently, had a switch in place to switch to a third monitor which has the same screen resolution as the lowest resolution one.

Primary 1080p
Secondary 1024x768 on both

It does not work under windows 8.1 or kubuntu 14.04 now

all connected with vga cable.

The switch did work but now it doesn't. I just get a blue screen and no signal output. I know the tv with vga input works because I have connected it to a small netbook and successfully output the desktop to it.

nvidia GeForce GT 705 graphics card and nvidia-settings drivers

Hope someone can advise

Thanks

Comment: You should update your question not use comments for informaton like that.  If the switch worked, and now it doesn't, the problem is sort of ovbious.  The switch no longer works and should be replaced with working hardware.

Comment: it isn't that obvious. I tried to bypass the switch and it still does not work!!

Comment: What doesn't work the third monitor?  I would be shocked if that GPU could support three monitors.  Have you tried to replace the kvm switch?

Comment: It can't support three monitors. It is a hardware switch. So only two monitors are active at a time. I have tried plugging in the monitor that does not work straight to the vga port on the computer - bi-passing the hardware switch - it still displays a blue screen.

Comment: I take it all back. It did turn out to be the switch that failed. I think the issue was that  I was trying to bypass it in a hurry and the monitor hadn't been configured for use.